# How do I take text from only checked radiobutton and send it to listbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I was thinking about "if" statement to make it work, but I don't really understand how to connect it to "checked event". I am a beginner so please don't be rough on me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, radiobuttons are in a same group. So we can let their `CheckedChanged` event subscribe to a same method.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    radioButton1.CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged;
    radioButton2.CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged;
    radioButton3.CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged;
}
```

Then use the parameter `sender` to get the selected radiobutton.

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clear listbox
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    // Add the selected radiobutton into listbox
    listBox1.Items.Add(((RadioButton)sender).Text);
}
```

The test result,

[image]